# AVD screen recording doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, android-studio

I wanted to ask question here so I recorded the screen of AVD. But this is the result I get. Is there a solution to this problem? If not, how can I record AVD screen?[image]

P.S. AVD works without problem when I record screen, but recording is like this.

Comment: I have the same issue. did you solve the problem?

Comment: @Arst, no unfortunately. I used the game bar as described in the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a graphics glitch, here's a few things you could try (one at a time):

- restart the AVD (cold boot)
- go into the settings in your AVD and setting the *Emulated performance: Graphics* to Software instead of Hardware (or vice versa)
- wipe the AVD's data, or delete it and create a new one
- use a different system image (my API 23 one has graphics issues)
- update your video drivers (if you're using Hardware graphics)

otherwise you might want to use some video capture software to record the emulator window instead. Personally I've used the Windows 10 Game Bar to record video and it works fine, plus it captures sound! [Here's how to do that](https://www.theverge.com/2020/4/21/21222533/record-screen-pc-windows-laptop-xbox-game-bar-how-to) if it's something you want to try

Comment: Write know I don't have that good internet connection, so I tried Game Bar and it was awesome. Thank you

Comment: Nice! Also you can go to *Captures Settings* (type it into the start menu) and adjust things like video quality and framerate if you need a smoother capture

Comment: The recording using gamebar stopped when i rotated the screen on android emulator

Comment: @SonuSanjeev at a guess it's because the window you're recording is changing dimensions (possibly being destroyed in the process) so the capture can't continue. You'd probably have to record your whole screen and crop to the area that shows the emulator, but the game bar won't allow that, so you'd need to find some other capture software. Or if you don't need to catch the rotation animation, start a new capture after you rotate, and combine the two clips in some editing software

Comment: @cactustictacs Yes, it should probably be because of dimension change, updating the AVD settings worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the cable provides too little bandwidth; just record the emulator instead.